# wp_list_categories() not listing categories

Tags: categories

I've many categories in my database but when i'm calling `wp_list_categories()` it is not listing any categories, its only outputting

```
Categories
  No categories
```

Also, I'm trying to populate it using `get_categories()` but still same problem, it outputting as if there were no category

Comment: Are these categories listed in the backend? Check if all of them have posts associated as these functions hide empty categories by default.

Comment: no, none of them have posted associated with them. Still, what functions can i use to access all the categories??

Comment: Check my answer below...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wp_list_categories` or `get_categories`, just pass `hide_empty = 0` to it. This will get you even those categories which do not have any posts associated with them.

Ex: `$cats = get_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0));`

Answer (score -1):

## NOTE!

if you use that **inside loop**, then you'd use **`get_posts()`** instead of `get_categories()`;

```
$desired_category_ID = 239;
$desired_post_type = 'post';

$array =  get_posts('child_of'=>$desired_category_ID ,    'post_type'=> $desired_post_type);    $out='';
foreach ($array as $key=> $value) {
    $out .= '<li class="manual_posts"><a href="'.get_permalink($value->ID).'">'.$value->post_title.'</a></li>';
}
echo $out;
```